# Как разлогинить сразу всех пользователей?

Tags: php

Есть проект написанный на PHP. Как мне разлогинить сразу всех пользователей системы. Используется виртуальный хостинг. Доступа к настройкам PHP нет. Проект реализован по паттерну MVC. Полностью самописный.

```
    class UserController {

    public function actionAuthorize(){

        $login = '';
        $password = '';
        $passwordRequired = false;

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $login = $_POST['login'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];

            $errors = false;

            if (!empty($login)) {
                if (!empty($password)) {
                    $user = User::checkUserData($login, $password);
                    if ($user == false) {
                        $errors[] = 'Неверные учетные данные';
                    }
                }else{
                    $errors[] = 'Введите пароль';
                    $passwordRequired = true;
                }
                if ($errors == false) {
                    User::auth($user);
                    if ( ! DEVELOPE_MODE || ( User::getUserGroup() == 'admin' ? true : false ) ) {
                        header("Location: /");
                    } else {
                        $errors[] = 'Идёт обноаление сайта!';
                        unset($_SESSION['user']);
                    }
                }
            }else{
                $errors[] = 'Введите логин';
            }
        }

        require_once ROOT . '/views/user/login.php';

        return true;
    }

    public function actionLogout(){

        unset($_SESSION['user']);
        header("Location: /");
        return true;
    }
}

class User{
    // Лишние методы убрал
    public static function auth($user){

        $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
    }
}
```

Comment: Предоставьте больше информации, на каком фреймворке написано ваше приложение? Как осуществляется сессия пользователей? (одноразовые токены, где сохраняются и тд)

Comment: @Алексей подправил)

Answer (score 1):

Ну вообще зависит от способа хранения сессий.
Если хранится в базе, то очищаете таблицу с сессиями. 
Если на файлах, то нужно очистить папку, в которой хранятся файлы сессий.

Если нет возможности это чистить, то можно сделать что-то вроде костыля:
в таблицу с пользователями добавляете колонку, needLogout, если нужно всех разлогинить то выставляете эту колонку в true, а в месте, где пользователь авторизовывается проверять эту колонку, и очищать сессию в случае чего и needLogout переводить в false

upd: тут подсказали, что место хранения сессий можете узнать так:

```
$p = ini_get('session.save_path'); 
printf("Обработчик сессий: %s\n", ini_get('session.save_handler')); 
printf("Место хранения сессий: %s\n", $p ? $p : sys_get_temp_dir());
```

Comment: Вставьте в свой ответ `$p = ini_get('session.save_path');
printf("Обработчик сессий: %s\n", ini_get('session.save_handler'));
printf("Место хранения сессий: %s\n", $p ? $p : sys_get_temp_dir());` если не сложно

Comment: Место хранения сессий - это хорошо. Но доступ к ним запрещён. Про БД это первая мысль рождённая в моей голове, но это не лучший вариант, возрастёт нагрузка, не? Грубо говоря это флаг авторизации.